# how to show only unique date string among all date string which repeated many times

Tags: php

I retrieve date strings from url.
my code for retrieving date strings is given below date string are store in $item[6].it works fine.But in date strings date are repeated many times.i want to show only unique date not all date .how can i do this.please help me thanks.

```
  function curlUsingGet($url, $data)
 {

 if(empty($url) OR empty($data))
{
    return 'Error: invalid Url or Data';
}

$fields_string = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$urlStringData = $url.'?'.$fields_string;
 $_SESSION['urlStringData']=$urlStringData;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT
 6.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
$header = array("Cache-Control: no-cache");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urlStringData);

$return = curl_exec($ch);
 $date = explode('|',$return);

    for($i=0;$i<count($date);$i++)
    {

    $arraylist[]= $date[$i];


    }
        $arraylist;
        foreach($arraylist as $allitem)
        {
        $item= explode('~',$allitem);
        print"</br>";
        echo $item[6];




        }

        curl_close($ch);

    }
             $a='UMESH NARAIN SHARMA';
     $b='ald';
    $data = array('u' => $a , 'b'=> $b );
    echo 
    curlUsingGet('http://localhost/causelist/CauseListData',$data);

    ?>


the output is

  2014-03-10
 2014-03-10
 2014-03-06
 2014-03-06
 2014-03-06
 2014-03-06
 2014-03-06
2014-03-06
2014-03-06
2014-03-06
2014-03-06
2014-03-06
2014-03-10
2014-03-10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dates as an array, you can use array_unique() to remove duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
<?php
$input = array("green", "red", "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/array_unique) if you wish to store in one array and print

or you can use [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array) function to remove duplicate

```
 $arraylist;
 foreach($arraylist as $allitem)
 {
    $item= explode('~',$allitem);
    print"</br>";               
     // check for date which is exist in array so do not print it
    if (!in_array($item[6], $os)) {
        echo $item[6];
    }
   $temp_arr[] = $item[6];
 }
```

hope this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the dates in an associative array instead, this would give you only unique values.

```
$date = explode('|',$return);
for($i=0;$i<count($date);$i++)
{
    $arraylist[$date[$i]] => 1;
}
```